# Wireless adapter problems

Tags: wireless, 18.04, devices

I recently tried three different wireless adapters that should work with Ubuntu, but I'm not getting anywhere.

The computer does not recognize the devices. I tried to get some drivers to install, but none of them is working.

Can you help me out?
I have tried all of the solutions online, but it's getting nowhere.

Comment: Did you reboot to see if they would work?

Comment: Please insert one and run the terminal command: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result.